# PHP 7: XPath - How to simplify this query?

Tags: php, xpath

From HTML page: https://www.topazlabs.com/downloads
I want extract Topaz ReMask version number for Windows as string: v5.0.1

1. I download HTML with curl
2. I use query:

like this ;

```
 ->finder->query("//div[contains(@class, 'wpb_wrapper')]/.//a[text()[contains(.,'Topaz ReMask')]]/../../../div");

OR

...->finder->query("//div[contains(@class, 'wpb_wrapper')]//a[text()[contains(.,'Topaz ReMask')]]/../../../div");
```

3. Then I look for all DIV tags to search the one with this two strings "/" and "(Win)", something like this: $versionString = Find($nodes, "/", "(Win)");
4. I process text to extract only Windows version.

It works, but can it be simplified?

The HTML part of the page I work with is this:

```
...
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <div class="vc_empty_space" style="height: 20px">
    <span class="vc_empty_space_inner">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="mpc_textblock-975b2251c2a82c7" class="mpc-textblock mpc-init mpc-typography--preset_2 ">
    <p>
      <a href="/remask" target="blank">Topaz ReMask</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="mpc-tooltip-wrap" data-id="mpc_textblock-615b2251c2a8c4a">
    <div id="mpc_textblock-615b2251c2a8c4a" class="mpc-textblock mpc-init mpc-typography--preset_0 ">
      <p>
        <em>v5.0.3 (Mac) / v5.0.1 (Win)
        </em>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="mpc_tooltip-925b2251c2a8d2f" class="mpc-tooltip mpc-init mpc-typography--preset_4 mpc-position--left mpc-can-hover mpc-trigger--hover ">Mac Updated November 4, 2016
      <br>Windows Updated November 21, 2016
      <div class="mpc-arrow">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mpc_textblock-475b2251c2a9601" class="mpc-textblock mpc-init ">
    <p>The quickest and easiest way to mask your photo.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could base it on the text content only. Using `DOMXpath::evaluate()` you can fetch the string directly:

```
$document= new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = "substring-after(
  //div[contains(.//p, 'Topaz ReMask')]//text()[starts-with(., 'Windows Updated ')],
  'Windows Updated '
)";

var_dump($xpath->evaluate($expression));
```

Output:

```
string(24) "November 21, 2016
      "
```

Xpath expression

- get any `div` that has a `p` with the text `Topaz ReMask`, ...
  `//div[contains(.//p, 'Topaz ReMask')]`
- ...the text descendant nodes that start with `Windows Updated`...
  `//div[contains(.//p, 'Topaz ReMask')]//text()[starts-with(., 'Windows Updated ')]`
- ... and extract the text after `Windows Updated`:

```
    substring-after(
      //div[contains(.//p, 'Topaz ReMask')]//text()[starts-with(., 'Windows Updated ')],
      'Windows Updated '
    )
```